# assembly version match with team foundation server build

Tags: c#

I am curious how to version my assembly.

Is this good enough or should I use a standard like 1.0.1234.1 and match the build version to my TFS build id?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: why down vote? give me an explanation ftw.

Comment: this thread goes farther for me in the sense that the release processes, which is part of the build definition, can be setup to increment your versions as part of the build and release using TFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out semantic versioning - 
http://semver.org
It recommends the following versioning scheme:

MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:

1.MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,

2.MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and

3.PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

Regarding phasing out an assembly, I don't think the versioning scheme you use would be impacted. You'd just stop releasing updates to that assembly.

Comment: how do I fix this question so I can ask questions again?